# Extract the first (or last) n characters of a string

Tags: string, r

I want to extract the first (or last) *n* characters of a string. This would be the equivalent to Excel's `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()`. A small example:

```
# create a string
a <- paste('left', 'right', sep = '')
a
# [1] "leftright"
```

I would like to produce `b`, a string which is equal to the first 4 letters of `a`:

```
b
# [1] "left"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

See `?substr`

```
R> substr(a, 1, 4)
[1] "left"
```

Comment: I recommend having a look at @juba's answer below. He provides a `stringr` solution.

Comment: Yeah, substr is a great answer if you only need to read from left to right, but useless if you need to read right to left. For example, if you don't know the number of characters in a string, just that you need to capture the last 10 characters, you cannot use substr; however, with str_sub("??1234567890", -10, -1) = "1234567890"

Answer (score 90):

The `stringr` package provides the `str_sub` function, which is a bit easier to use than `substr`, especially if you want to extract right portions of your string :

```
R> str_sub("leftright",1,4)
[1] "left"
R> str_sub("leftright",-5,-1)
[1] "right"
```

Comment: Thank for your hint, juba; by the way I think I will accept rcs' answer because it deals with base `R` :)

Comment: Knowing base R is good, but if it comes to string functions, your life will be easier if you only use the stringr as mentioned by @juba

Comment: I agree with Dieter. Learning `stringr` will save you almost as much aggravation as `lubridate`.

Answer (score 33):

You can easily obtain Right() and Left() functions starting from the Rbase package:

- right function

  ```
  right = function (string, char) {
      substr(string,nchar(string)-(char-1),nchar(string))
  }
  ```
- left function

  ```
  left = function (string,char) {
      substr(string,1,char)
  }
  ```

you can use those two custom-functions exactly as left() and right() in excel.
Hope you will find it useful

Answer (score 8):

Make it simple and use R basic functions:

```
# To get the LEFT part:
> substr(a, 1, 4)
[1] "left"
> 
# To get the MIDDLE part:
> substr(a, 3, 7)
[1] "ftrig"
> 
# To get the RIGHT part:
> substr(a, 5, 10)
[1] "right"
```

The `substr()` function tells you where start and stop `substr(x, start, stop)`

Answer (score 7):

For those coming from Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets, you would have seen functions like `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, and `MID()`. I have created a package known as **forstringr** and its development version is currently on [Github](https://github.com/gbganalyst/forstringr).

```
if(!require("devtools")){
 install.packages("devtools")
}

devtools::install_github("gbganalyst/forstringr")

library(forstringr)
```

- the `str_left()`: This counts from the left and then extract n characters
- the `str_right()`- This counts from the right and then extract n characters
- the `str_mid()`- This extract characters from the middle

**Examples:**

```
x <- "some text in a string"

str_left(x, 4)

[1] "some"

str_right(x, 6)

[1] "string"

str_mid(x, 6, 4)

[1] "text"
```