# Separate a column without separators

Tags: r, columnsorting

I have a dataset with a column that consists of a code and a number and I am trying to separate that column just to get the code.

```
df <- data.frame(code=rep(c('2d01', '2m04', '3C06', 'CrD05'), each=10),
                 pos=rep(c(3, 7,2,4), times=20))
df<-extract(df,code,into = c("code","number"),
            "(.{2})(.{2})")
```

I tried this but I have a code with a different number of characters (CrD05) so it doesn't work.
Is there a way to separate the last 2 numbers and keep the rest?

Comment: We could use `"(.*)(\\d{2}$)"` as a pattern

Comment: [This is a similar question with nice answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897236/extract-the-first-or-last-n-characters-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gsub to extract the last two characters

```
df$code2 = gsub("\\d{2}$", "", df$code)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking to remove the last 2 numbers so I can keep the code

Comment: I misunderstood, I edit my answer

Comment: If I also wanted to remove the letter how could I code it?